# Import .obj error, Sequences of dimension 0 Contain 3 items, not 2

Tags: python, objects, export, import, obj

Good afternoon,

I'm having issues importing a .obj file of the USS Ticonderoga (purchased from vendor). Whenever I try to import it, I get the error shown in the image below **(sequences of dimension 0 should contain 3 items not 2)**. The .mtl file is in the same directory as the .obj file. Blender version is 2.91.

I can confirm that the .obj file is openable using 3DView.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can confirm this is a bug in Blender's OBJ importer. I filed a bug report for you: https://developer.blender.org/T89421

You can work around the bug in the meantime. Your model should have come with a .mtl file. Open it in a text editor and look for any lines that have a `-s`, like this

```
map_Kd -s 2.000 2.000 texture.jpg
```

The `Kd`, `2.000`, and `texture.jpg` parts might be different for you. The important part is that there are two numbers after `-s`. You need to add a third number, a `1`

```
map_Kd -s 2.000 2.000 1 texture.jpg
```

Do that for all these lines, save, and the import should now work.